# Hibernate Many to Many Bidirectional Mapping with using Java List

Tags: java, sql, mysql, hibernate, postgresql

I am trying to make a many to many example with hibernate using java List. My codes are as follows, I am getting some erros. If someone can help me to solve this, it would be great

A Student can take many courses
A course can be taken by many students

```
                     Student ---->STUDENT_COURSE<-----Course
```

Student Class:

```
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable 
{
    private long studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private List<Course> courses = new LinkedList<Course>();
        //other getters and setters

}
```

Course Class:

```
public class Course implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long courseId;
    private String courseName;
    private List <Student> Stu = new LinkedList <Student>();
        //other getters and setters
}
```

Course Mapping File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 14, 2010 7:14:32 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.Beta1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.BiddingSystem.domain.Course" table="COURSE">
        <id name="courseId" type="long">
            <column name="COURSEID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="courseName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="COURSENAME" />
        </property>
        <list name="Stu"  table="STUDENT_COURSE">
            <key>
                <column name="COURSEID" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many column="STUDENTID"  class="com.BiddingSystem.domain.Student" />
        </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Student Mapping File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 14, 2010 7:14:32 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.Beta1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.BiddingSystem.domain.Student" table="STUDENT">
        <id name="studentId" type="long">
            <column name="STUDENTID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="studentName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="STUDENTNAME" />
        </property>
        <list name="courses"  table="STUDENT_COURSE">
            <key>
                <column name="STUDENTID" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many column="COURSEID" class="com.BiddingSystem.domain.Course" />
        </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Error:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource com/BiddingSystem/domain/Student.hbm.xml
[WARN] /biddingsystem/greet
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.BiddingSystem.server.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:16)
    at com.BiddingSystem.server.GreetingServiceImpl.<init>(GreetingServiceImpl.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource com/BiddingSystem/domain/Student.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:671)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1679)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1647)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1626)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1600)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1520)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1506)
    at com.BiddingSystem.server.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from invalid mapping
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:668)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "list" must match "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,key,(index|list-index),(element|one-to-many|many-to-many|composite-element|many-to-any),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,sql-delete-all?,filter*)".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:2017)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:901)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2938)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:601)
    ... 34 more
[WARN] Nested in java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource com/BiddingSystem/domain/Student.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:671)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1679)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1647)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1626)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1600)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1520)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1506)
    at com.BiddingSystem.server.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    at com.BiddingSystem.server.GreetingServiceImpl.<init>(GreetingServiceImpl.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from invalid mapping
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:668)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "list" must match "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,key,(index|list-index),(element|one-to-many|many-to-many|composite-element|many-to-any),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,sql-delete-all?,filter*)".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:2017)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:901)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2938)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:601)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a Set rather than a List. To map a List you need an additional column which specifies the index within the list each member is present at (an  or  element).

In my experience, it's best to avoid Hibernate's List-mapping support.

Comment: The problem is that I am using a widget that needs the java list. I need to get this list working!!

Comment: Can someone help to get the list work with hibernate for one to many, many to one and many to many

Comment: You can easily convert the set to a list just by copying it into an ArrayList, for example. Although you should think about what order you want the list to be in, and whether that order is specified in the database, or just the result of sorting.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think hibernate's list should be avoided? I think it is very useful.

Comment: @abhijeet It can only be used as inverse=false, and (at least in the version of Hibernate I was using at the time, which was probably Hibernate 2) it always started by nulling the parent/index columns and then resetting them, whereas in fact those columns should never really be null. I didn't really encounter any cases in which I actually wanted to store a list, as opposed to an ordered set which worked much better and didn't outrage our DBAs.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387806/how-to-map-many-to-many-list-in-hibernate-with-a-link-table). It will solve your probem, probably.

Comment: Ya, I used this implementation but getting a bunch of errors with it. The implementation above is the same implementation

Comment: It seems like it cannot parse list block. Instead of <key><column name="STUDENTID" /></key>, can you try with <key column="STUDENTID" /> ?

Comment: No, unfortunately, it fails even by changing the column tag. Is there any tools that can generate proper mapping file, I'm fed writing these mapping files